# Web API Attribute Routing URI Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I want to route my API through this URI

```
localhost/api/ServiceA/1234
```

where isbn=1234

currently I am retrieving json from the UrI mentioned below

```
localhost/1234
```

where 1234 is isbn

How can I get the same json results with the following uri?

```
localhost/api/ServiceA/1234
```

Currently I am getting null with the above URL

With the following code using attribute routing I am getting the results with

I have an API Countroller

```
public class ServiceAController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/ServiceA/{isbn}")]
    public Book GetBook(string isbn)
    {
        using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var query = from b in db.Books
                        where b.ISBN == isbn && b.Source == "Book Store 1"
                        select b;
            return query.SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to keep the `[HttpGet]` attribute for your method.

Ex:

```
[Route("api/ServiceA/{isbn}")]
[HttpGet]
public Book GetBook(string isbn){
    // ...
}
```